# Jquery: ajax explain code

Tags: ajax, jquery

This is some code i made up following a course:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'XML',
        url: 'user_timeline.xml',
        success: processXML
    });

    function processXML(response){
        var status = $(response).find("status");
        for (var i=0; i < status.length; i++){
            var text = $("text",status[i]).text();
            $('#status').append("<p>" + text + "</p>");
        };
    }
});
```

It works fine, but can someone explain this:

```
$("text",status[i])
```

Does it search/select the status array for the key 'text'?

I want to know what i'm doing, not just doing it...

Comment: I would recommend opening up your browser dev tools and set a breakpoint at that line. Then you can step through and understand what each piece does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That specific line is looking for a `text` element inside `status[i]`.  See the jQuery docs on this:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Selector Context

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.
>   For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be
>   restricted like so:
>
> $('div.foo').click(function() {   $('span', this).addClass('bar'); });
>
> When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of
>   this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional
>   class.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

Comment: Thank you, but do you have a more direct link explaining this syntax?

Comment: @Nomistake, check out the link I put in my answer, specifically the section near the top titled _Selector Context_.